# How to keep a time zone during Joda DateTime serialization?

Tags: java, spring, datetime, serialization, jodatime

I'm trying to transfer an object that contains a field of `DateTime` type from one Spring Boot application to another. Although the object is transferred correctly, its timezone is always reset to clear UTC (for example, if I send 06:00 with UTC+7 timezone, I receive 23:00 of previous day with UTC+0 timezone). Is there a good way to fix it? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are You transfering the object? Java serialization? REST call?

Comment: REST call. Jackson is used for serialization

Comment: Can You call the REST endpoint manually, and see what is the date format set? You probably have data format set that skips the zone part....

Comment: You can make your life easier by using `ZonedDateTime` in JDK 8. Joda Time is superseded by `java.time`.

Comment: I started the app in debug mode. On the first line I have a date _2019-02-14T06:40:00.000+07:00_. On the second line I set a format with time zone to my object mapper (`objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"));`). Then I call `writeValue` and finally get _2019-02-13T23:40:00.000Z_.

Comment: @WildWind03
I dont get it, how come You set date format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ" but get 2019-02-13T23:40:00.000Z that does not correspond to the format?